# c# + Using dynamicmethod with an attribute

Tags: c#, dynamicmethod

```
[CustomAttribute]
public bool IsGreen()
{
   return true;
}
```

How could one write the above using a DynamicMethod in c#?

UPDATE; per casperOne you cannot do this with a custom attribute.

**But** what about a non-custom attribute such as:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public bool IsGreen()
{
   return true;
}
```

Note:  I created a new post, because my last one missed the point which is:
What im driving at is...how do i dynamically create a method that contains an attribute?

Also, i asked about using DynamicMethod, is there a better way?

Comment: This question does not mention AT&T syntax at all - retagged `[att]` removed

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  From the note in the remarks section for the documentation for the [`IsDefined` method on the `DynamicMethod` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.isdefined.aspx):

> Custom attributes are not currently
>   supported on dynamic methods.

If you want to create dynamic methods then you will have to create an assembly/module/type/method dynamically and then attach the attributes to that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, im trying to wrap my head around what can/cannot be done and how.  What about a method with a non-custom attribute?  Im updating my post above.